# How to push only updated docker images to Sitecore Managed Cloud ACR

Tags: docker, sitecore-managed-cloud

**Sitecore XP 10.2 and Sitecore Managed Cloud Containers**

We are using the CI pipeline to build the docker images and push the images to ACR. While pushing the image to ACR, we are tagging all the images with the build number tag. So, all the images get the build number tag and then we are updating the `docker-image.json` file with the updated tag for all the images.

Since this is XP set up, there are so many xdb-related images like *prc*, *cortexreporting*, *xdbautomation* etc for which we are not updating the code but we have kept a dockerfile in case of future enhancements are required, that's why custom images for these roles get built every time we run the docker build command and all these images are pushed to ACR with the new tag.

I'd like to know if there is a way to push only those images to ACR which are updated since the last build.

Comment: But they're not acually pushing. If the underlying layers of the container image have not changed, they're not physically being pushed

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mark. Since with every docker build, we are giving a unique pipeline build-id as the tag to all the images, ACR is considering them as new images and creating a new tag folder.

Comment: No it's not. That's not how Container Storage works.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkCassidy, I understand ACR only keeps the delta. So while we may have a lot of tags, it doesn't take up much space. But the issue is with Sitecore Manage cloud implementation, which makes us to change the tag of custom images each time we want to do a deployment. Sitecore has a config/docker-images/docker-images.json that spells out each image used in the deployment.